# Printing Tree Data Structure Alphabetically

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a big task to do as an exercise for Data Structures and algorithms, and part of it is to modify this tree data structure to print the tree in an alphabetical order.I won't post the whole task because it is huge. Im stuck on the last part which asks me to modify the given tree Data Structure to print the tree in an alphabetical order. I am stuck on it for couple of days and simple don't have any idea how to do it. Any help would be appriciated, thanks. My opinion is that i have to somehow modify the printTreeRecursive() method.

For example the current data structure will print a tree like this:

```
c: d c b a
```

(The first added child is printed last).

Where c: is the root and d c b a are his children

But im supposed to modify it to look like this:

```
c: a b c d
```

Here is the data structure:

```
public class SLLTree<E> implements Tree<E> {

    // SLLNode is the implementation of the Node interface
    class SLLNode<P> implements Node<P> {

        // Holds the links to the needed nodes
        SLLNode<P> parent, sibling, firstChild;

        // Hold the data
        P element;

        public SLLNode(P o) {
            element = o;
            parent = sibling = firstChild = null;
        }

        public P getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public void setElement(P o) {
            element = o;
        }

    }

    protected SLLNode<E> root;

    public SLLTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public Node<E> root() {
        return root;
    }

    public Tree.Node<E> parent(Tree.Node<E> node) {
        return ((SLLNode<E>) node).parent;
    }

    public int childCount(Tree.Node<E> node) {
        SLLNode<E> tmp = ((SLLNode<E>) node).firstChild;
        int num = 0;
        while (tmp != null) {
            tmp = tmp.sibling;
            num++;
        }
        return num;
    }

    public void makeRoot(E elem) {
        root = new SLLNode<E>(elem);
    }

    public Node<E> addChild(Node<E> node, E elem) {
        SLLNode<E> tmp = new SLLNode<E>(elem);
        SLLNode<E> curr = (SLLNode<E>) node;
        tmp.sibling = curr.firstChild;
        curr.firstChild = tmp;
        tmp.parent = curr;
        return tmp;
    }

    public void remove(Tree.Node<E> node) {
        SLLNode<E> curr = (SLLNode<E>) node;
        if (curr.parent != null) {
            if (curr.parent.firstChild == curr) {
                // The node is the first child of its parent
                // Reconnect the parent to the next sibling
                curr.parent.firstChild = curr.sibling;
            } else {
                // The node is not the first child of its parent
                // Start from the first and search the node in the sibling list
                // and remove it
                SLLNode<E> tmp = curr.parent.firstChild;
                while (tmp.sibling != curr) {
                    tmp = tmp.sibling;
                }
                tmp.sibling = curr.sibling;
            }
        } else {
            root = null;
        }
    }

    class SLLTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        SLLNode<T> start, current;

        public SLLTreeIterator(SLLNode<T> node) {
            start = node;
            current = node;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (current != null);
        }

        public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
            if (current != null) {
                SLLNode<T> tmp = current;
                current = current.sibling;
                return tmp.getElement();
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }

        public void remove() {
            if (current != null) {
                current = current.sibling;
            }
        }
    }

    public Iterator<E> children(Tree.Node<E> node) {
        return new SLLTreeIterator<E>(((SLLNode<E>) node).firstChild);
    }

    void printTreeRecursive(Node<E> node, int level) {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        int i;
        SLLNode<E> tmp;

        for (i = 0; i < level; i++)
            System.out.print("  ");
        System.out.println(node.getElement().toString());
        tmp = ((SLLNode<E>) node).firstChild;

        while (tmp != null) {
            printTreeRecursive(tmp, level + 1);
            tmp = tmp.sibling;
        }
    }

    public void printTree() {
        printTreeRecursive(root, 0);
    }

    public int countMaxChildren() {
        return countMaxChildrenRecursive(root);
    }

    int countMaxChildrenRecursive(SLLNode<E> node) {
        int t = childCount(node);
        SLLNode<E> tmp = node.firstChild;
        while (tmp != null) {
            t = Math.max(t, countMaxChildrenRecursive(tmp));
            tmp = tmp.sibling;
        }
        return t;
    }

}
```

```
public interface Tree<E> {
    // //////////Accessors ////////////

    public Tree.Node<E> root();

    public Tree.Node<E> parent(Tree.Node<E> node);

    public int childCount(Tree.Node<E> node);

    // //////////Transformers ////////////
    public void makeRoot(E elem);

    public Tree.Node<E> addChild(Tree.Node<E> node, E elem);

    public void remove(Tree.Node<E> node);

    // //////////Iterator ////////////
    public Iterator<E> children(Tree.Node<E> node);

    // //////Inner interface for tree nodes ////////
    public interface Node<E> {

        public E getElement();

        public void setElement(E elem);

    }
}
```

```
public class SLLTreeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tree.Node<String> a, b, c, d;

    SLLTree<String> t = new SLLTree<String>();

    t.makeRoot("C:");

    a = t.addChild(t.root, "Program files");
    b = t.addChild(a, "CodeBlocks");
    c = t.addChild(b, "codeblocks.dll");
    c = t.addChild(b, "codeblocks.exe");
    b = t.addChild(a, "Nodepad++");
    c = t.addChild(b, "langs.xml");
    d = c;
    c = t.addChild(b, "readme.txt");
    c = t.addChild(b, "notepad++.exe");
    a = t.addChild(t.root, "Users");
    b = t.addChild(a, "Darko");
    c = t.addChild(b, "Desktop");
    c = t.addChild(b, "Downloads");
    c = t.addChild(b, "My Documents");
    c = t.addChild(b, "My Pictures");
    b = t.addChild(a, "Public");
    a = t.addChild(t.root, "Windows");
    b = t.addChild(a, "Media");

    t.printTree();

    t.remove(d);
    t.printTree();

    System.out.println("The maximum number of children is "
            + t.countMaxChildren());

}

}
```

Comment: Could you also show how you initialize the tree before printing?

Comment: Okay i will add a SLLTreeTest example class to show.

Comment: Nobody got any idea? :/

Comment: I would think about creating a Collection where I would sort by inserting the nodes and I would traverse the tree in a breadth-first fashion and build up my Collection in the process. The result of this would be a sorted collection and I would just sequentially traverse that and print it. However, I am not sure this would be a solution for you, as the requirement was to modify the data-structure. So I would need more information about the task to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: What kind of Tree is this? Do you need to traverse the tree, sort it and print it - or do you have to modify the structure so that it is sorted like a search tree?

Comment: If i can do it with traversing and sorting, i don't have to modify the structure :)

Comment: Well, then simply create a collection and traverse the tree (google Tree Traversal) like however you want and put every node's element in the collection. If you want to support duplicates in your tree, create a List and sort it afterwards with Collections.sort() or if you want to eliminate duplicates use a SortedSet. Hope this helps :)

Comment: The answer helps but i can't find a method for non binary Tree Traversal :/

Answer (score 0):

As I see, my initial suggestion is good-enough for the asker and other commenters as well. So, as this is a studying task, I will not write code as an answer (I would take all the fun, wouldn't I?). I will share some important checkpoints to reach in the thought process, which, if reached should lead to the solution:

- we need a `Collection`
- we need to use a breadth-first traversing (`printTreeRecursive` is a good example)
- we need to look at the `while` cycle of `printTreeRecursive`, as it is key to reach a traversing
- whenever we reach a `node`, we should [insert sort](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/InsertionSort.htm) the node into the collection
- after the traversing, we iterate the `Collection` and print out its elements